# Was the unfinished Drums of Tombalku rewritten as Xuthal of the Dusk by Robert E. Howard?

Tags: conan, robert-e-howard

Robert E. Howard left many stories unfinished or unpublished.  After his death, Lin Carter and L. Sprague de Camp finished many incomplete stories, and they also reworked stories that featured other heroes into Conan stories.  Reading through the collected Conan stories, I found this jarring on a number of occasions, and I am curious whether there is more information about one particular instance.

The story "Drums of Tombalku" was left incomplete at Howard's death, with a synopsis of some of what remained to be written.  However, reading this story and "[The Slithering Shadow](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0601051.txt)" (Howard's original title was "Xuthal of the Dusk") back to back, it certainly seemed like the unfinished "Drums" has been reworked to become the latter Conan story.  As such, it seemed foolish and inappropriate for it to be rewritten again and published as a separate story.

However, this was just an inkling that I had.  I am wondering whether there is any documentary evidence that the two stories represent successive drafts of a single narrative.  [This Conan fan site](http://www.pulpanddagger.com/conan/adventur.html) suggests the same thing, but again that is admitted supposition.